# Can NodeJS HTTPS module make both http and https requests through it's get method?

Tags: node.js, express, http, https

Am I correct in assuming it can because it is built on top of the HTTP module?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: No. I am too lazy and I am trying to harness the power of the interwebs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Https cannot make http calls. :(